# In MediaQuery, is it normal for an element to have a certain property that we set for it in a certain width before it reaches that width?

Tags: html, css

I set flex-basis: 50% for screens with widths from 767px to 1199px, and for screens with widths from 1199px to above flex-basis: 25%, but I noticed that before we got to screens with widths of 1199px, flex-basis was equal to 25%, although I set flex-basis: 25% on screens that have a width of 1199px up (see picture). Is this normal?
See this picture for more clarification : [The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VptSg.jpg)
This is the code used :

```css
.portfolio {
  padding-top: var(--section-padding);
  padding-bottom: var(--section-padding);
}


}
.portfolio .imgs-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .portfolio .imgs-container .box {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1199px) {
  .portfolio .imgs-container .box {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
.portfolio .imgs-container .box img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="imgs-container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Awesome Image</h4>
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Thanks to everyone who answered, I finally understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific when setting media queries...

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1198px) {
  .portfolio .imgs-container .box {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1199px) {
  .portfolio .imgs-container .box {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```